# Proving that the expectation a random walk's value squared is bounded

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I've been having trouble on some probability homework question. It goes like this:

"Consider a biased random walk on the integers from $0$ to $N$ with probability of moving right of $p<1/2$ and probability of moving left of $1-p$. Let $S_n$ be the value of the walk at time $n$, and let $S_0=a$. Let $T$ be the first time the random walk reaches either $0$ or $N$, and definie $T_n := min\{n,T\}$. Let $Z_n = S_{T_n} + (1-2p)T_n$.

1. Show that $Z_n$ is a martingale.
2. Show that there exists a $C<\infty$ such that $\mathbb{E}(Z_n^2)<C$ for all n.

You can use the fact that every irreducible Markov chain on $0$ to $N$ has a $P<\infty$ and $\rho<1$ such that $P\{T > n\} \leq C \rho^n$, and that this implies that $\mathbb{E}(T)<\infty.$"

I've been able to prove 1, but I've gotten stuck on 2. I immediately tried to calculate $E[Z_n^2]$ directly by substituting $M_{T_n}$ for $Z_n$. When I expand I get
$$
E[M_{T_n}^2] = E\left[\left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{2S_{T_n}}\right] + (1-2p)E[T_n^2] - 2(1-2p)E\left[T_n\left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{S_{T_n}}\right].
$$
From here I want to give a uniform bound for each expected value in the right hand side. But, $E[T_n^2]$ so I can't figure out how to bound it without knowing $E[T]$. Similarly, I want to bound $E\left[T_n\left( \frac{1-p}{p} \right)^{S_{T_n}}\right]$ but this too seems to rely on T.

Comment: Why is $T$ or $T_n$ relevant for computing $E[Z_n^2]$ in the first place?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally defined $Z_n$ wrong. $Z_n := _{_}+(1−2)_$, and I edited that above. Good catch!

Comment: where did you define $M_{T_n}$?  Also your last paragraph seems to have linguistic problems e.g. "But, $E[T_n^]$ so I can't" isn't really a sentence and I don't know what it means.